# Do const string within the Update method improve performance?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, constants

In the method I can also save strings as const. Some strings, such as object infos, are very long. I want to know if `const` within **Update** (Tick) methods can solve the problem or should they be defined in the class body to increase performance?

```cs
public void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("Red sunrise in the sky."); // normal log

    const string info = "Red sunrise in the sky.";
    
    Debug.Log(info); // does it has better performance?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: The goal with constant is not performance but to improve the readability, and reusability and make your code easier to maintain.  If the sentence is going to be used in more places you declare it as a const so it can be reused and avoid spelling mistakes.

Comment: My guess is the performance would be the same. Strings known at compile-time, like in your example, should be interned, so the same instance would be used each time (not having the string multiple places in memory). But, is it really true that all the strings are constant. Do they not have some "variable" content also, like a date or an amount.

Comment: @srzsanti I think for the first time in one of the brackeys tutorials I realized that const can also affect performance. Of course, I used it mainly for the purpose you mentioned.

Comment: Affect whose performance? `Log` is called with a string value, no matter where this comes from. Log is the really expensive operation. Strings in C# are immutable and interned, so a const only avoids the allocation of a string the first time the method is called, nothing more. After that, the same string instance will be used. UNLESS you create the string dynamically

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Given that constants are inlined by the C# compiler, this actually compiles to the same bytecode, see https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugHQAiYAhgOYB2A9gM7BgDGjA3DjsgMxGoCAYQIBvHAUlF+yACwEAsgAoAlGIlTNZAKYAjAK7USAdQBOYYNqUAiAEraYBRvtrnG2gmFoFgACw+MANYAniTWKhwEAPRRBAymALaUEAQQ9NTc2JqarPS0zETohF4AZvQEALwEdg5OLm4eXj7+TiFhXNga2QQ6BkZmFlal9BHRsTD02oyewAS+lNO62sCWpgQADtqmZYmUtKzaAPxdBAC+OKdAA=== The performance is exactly the same, by definition.

Comment: If it is truly a constant it could be argued to allocate at class level rather than be allocating every frame.

Comment: @BugFinder That's not how constants work, see my link above

Answer (score 0):

You should to declare variables and constants in the Awake or Start method, just because the Update method is being called every single frame you have and it has no sense only for save 1 time the content.